# concatinating with a looped function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, concatenation

I was given a prompt that asks, 
   Finish the function canYouHearMe. Assume that there is a function 
called hello. It takes no parameters. Inside canYouHearMe, make a 
for loop that concatenates param with the result of invoking the 
function hello, 10 times.

This is what I have so far,

```js
function canYouHearMe(param){

    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
      return param.concat(hello())
    }
  }
```

I think the issue is that it concats param every time it calls hello and also I don't think the loop is actually running 10 times.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `return` will exit from the function. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to actually modify `param` that is passed in? Are you trying to return a concatinated list of responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i just figured it out,

```js
function canYouHearMe(param){
    var hi = ''
    //Code here
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
      hi += hello()
    }
    return param.concat(hi)
  }
```

haha every time i go here it's 2 seconds latter that i figure out the answer

Answer (score 2):

You're returning just at the first iteration.

**Assuming you're passing an array:**

```js
function hello() {
  return "Hello!";
}

function canYouHearMe(param) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    param = param.concat([hello()]);
  }
  return param;
}

var arr = canYouHearMe(["Ele "]);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Assuming you're passing a string:**

```js
function hello() {
  return "Hello!";
}

function canYouHearMe(param) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    param += hello();
  }
  return param;
}

var string = canYouHearMe("Ele ");
console.log(string);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```